# Deletion based on date of insertion of entry into table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, datetime

I want to know if oracle allows us to delete records from table which were inserted before a particular time and date if the table itself does not contain any Insertion_date column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **NO**. Oracle does not keep track of when a row was inserted. You have to create a column and add the data/time when the row was inserted to delete the row based on date. So in short you have to keep track of that by yourself.

Comment: You can also refer: [Change Data Capture](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/cdc.htm#DWHSG016) but note that it is not recommended and is desupported after I guess 11g.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle can show you table state on some time moment, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table AS OF TIMESTAMP sysdate - interval '1' minute
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Your answer is not matching with OP requirement

Comment: on some timestamp we can get data in table, and delete the other one base on results from current state

Comment: Provided [Flashback](http://learnappsdbarac.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-check-flashback-enabled-or-not.html) has been enabled

Comment: The answer is incomplete. To actually find the *new* rows would require either a self-join between the snapshot and the current state (if that's possible), or extracting the snapshot keys to a temporary table and do a left join with the current state. *Any* change capture mechanism would be faster than either option

Comment: Yeap I now, just post another variant of moving to goal, better then "no" :)